# High dynamic range: Can I feed ICtCp data directly to video encoder?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, hevc, hdr

When I go through the details of High dynamic range feature, I have come across ICtCp color format (Rec.2020). Is this similar to YCbCr? What is the exact difference between YCbCr and ICtCp? Can I pass ICtCp buffer to video encoder (H264/avc or H265/hevc) directly?

Comment: it's part of H.265, but not H.264.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jones. Looks like ICtCp can be given to encoder as input. No need of color conversion.

Comment: It does not matter that it is not part of H.264. It will still work.

Comment: As for YCbCr vs ICtCp: ICtCp is perceptually more uniform (basically giving you the same accuracy for a smaller bit depth) and also manages to properly separate luminosity from chromacity (unlike YCbCr) which greatly reduces artefacts due to chroma subsampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YCbCr and ICtCP are all luma/chroma color space. The difference between them is the chroma channels. HDR has been included in H.265. x265 only supported raw YUV or Y4M but you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wang, I understand that there is a difference in YUV and ICtCp w.r.t. chroma data. H.265 can accept ICtCp directly. What about H264? do we need to convert from ICtCp to YUV before feeding to H264?

Answer (score 0):

You can feed it, but only with zscale, not with old but more precise for old YCbCr swscale.

See commands here: https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg/issues/138

ffmpeg -v debug -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb48le -s:v 192x108 -i SCD_192x108.rgb48.rgb -vf format=gbrp16le,zscale=rangein=full:range=full:npl=10000:matrixin=input:transferin=smpte2084:primariesin=2020:matrix=ictcp:transfer=smpte2084:primaries=2020,format=yuv444p16le -f rawvideo FFMPEG_ICTCP_SCD_192x108.rgb48.plr.ffmpeg.yuv